# React to Shift+Tab in Gloss

Tags: haskell, interactive, gloss

I am currently writing a game using `gloss`' [`play`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.9.4.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss.html#v:play). The basic structure of this game is very simple: I have a board with units on it, one of which is in focus.

I have added the ability to change the focus by cycling through the units on the board using `KeyTab`. Quite quickly, I realised that I wanted to also be able to cycle back so I thought I'd use `Shift + KeyTab` to do so as is customary in this situation.

`gloss`' [`Event`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.9.4.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-IO-Game.html#t:Event) come with [`Modifiers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.9.4.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-IO-Game.html#t:Modifiers), one of which is `shift`. Perfect? Well... not quite: whenever I press `Shift + KeyTab`, the event is never received by the window (I used `Debug.Trace`'s `trace` to print all the received `Event`s).

With CAPS LOCK, I do receive `KeyTab` with the `shift` modifier marked as `Down`. If I switch to using `Ctrl + KeyTab` as my shortcut, it works perfectly well. Here is a minimal example reproducing the problem:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.Gloss
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game

data Board = Board Color Color Color

forward :: Board -> Board
forward (Board x y z) = Board y z x

backward :: Board -> Board
backward (Board x y z) = Board z x y

displayPoint :: Point -> Color -> Picture
displayPoint (x, y) c = translate x y $ color c $ circle 10

displayBoard :: Board -> Picture
displayBoard (Board x y z) =
  Pictures $ zipWith displayPoint coordinates [x, y, z]
  where coordinates = [(0, 30), (-30, -30), (30, -30)]

react :: Event -> Board -> Board
react (EventKey (SpecialKey KeyTab) Down mods _) b =
  case shift mods of
    Up   -> forward b
    Down -> backward b
react _ b = b

main :: IO ()
main =
  let window = InWindow "Buggy" (100, 100) (200, 200)
      board  = Board blue red yellow
  in play window black 24 board displayBoard react (const id)
```

Comment: For me, on OS-X the shift+tab combination is coming through as `EventKey (Char '\EM') Down (Modifiers {shift = Down, ctrl = Up, alt = Up})`.  And since `SpecialKey KeyTab /= Char '\EM'` we have a problem.  I'm not sure where the bug sits, this might be very much a platform specific issue.  You could just roll with it and treat `(Char '\EM')` the same as tab.

Comment: The event is not even received by the application in my case! It's a weird one. I really don't get it given that these shortcuts are already used by other programs (eg. chrome).